# Hanging dry wall on mass loaded vinyl - can I glue and screw

Tags: drywall, sound-proofing, sound-deadening

I am finishing a basement and had a question about hanging drywall on top of MLV (Mass loaded vinyl).

The basement I am finishing has MLV fastened to the ceiling joists.

I am getting ready to hang the drywall on the ceiling and I was wondering about if/what glue I can use.

Normally you can glue and screw the drywall To ceiling (i.e liquid nails and screws)

In the case of mass loaded vinyl what do I do? Can you use liquid nail? Should I use green-glue? Is there a special glue to use? Or do I not glue at all and maybe just add some extra screws.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the MLV was not bonded to the joists, then there is no value in gluing the sheetrock to the MLV. Add extra screws if you like, but a standard screw pattern of 6 screws per joist will suffice. I know it is not part of your question, but RC-1 channel is a really cost effective way to add a lot of sound deadening to the ceiling in addition to the MLV, if it is done properly. It only lowers the ceiling an additional 1/2"-5/8"